# Delphi 2006 duplicate function names

Tags: delphi

is there a way to make the Delphi compiler recognize and report duplicated function names (especially defined in different Units that the currently compiled unit uses)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't.  It would sure be nice if there was, though.  You can get around this by using the unit name of the function you'd like to invoke:

```
uses
  unit1, unit2;

procedure DoSomethingFromUnit1;
begin
  unit1.DoSomething;
end;
```

Try submitting this to QC as a feature request.  It would be a useful thing to have.

Answer (score 1):

From the sight of the compiler, duplicate function names are not duplicate if they reside in different scopes. Finding these ambiguities (in sight of the programmer) is supported quite well by [Pascal Analyzer](http://www.peganza.com/#PAL).

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those things that makes "WITH" so dangerous.

[CodeHealer](http://www.socksoftware.com/codehealer.php) does a good job of reporting when a method or identifier is hiding another one with the same name but a different scope.